# MS SQL Выбор даты в результате сравнения по двум полям

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица с полями customer_id, id, start_date и end_date, с такой структурой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно для каждого кастомера выбрать дату из **end_date**, которая будет < следующего за ним **start_date**, иначе NULL

т.е. для customer_id = 1122 это будет 28.10.2019, т.к. следующий **start_date** 30.10.2019 > **end_date** 28.10.2019

а для customer_id = 1200 будет NULL, т.к. все следующие **start_date** < предыдущих **end_date**

Comment: Читайте описание функции `LAG()`. Окно по `customer_id` с сортировкой по `id` (если именно `id` определяет, какая запись предыдущая/следующая). *для каждого кастомера выбрать дату из end_date, которая* А если таких несколько?

Comment: @Akina да, id определяет предыдущую/следующую запись. Ваш вопрос не понял. что подразумевается под A?

Comment: Ну если в данных несколько таких дат...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если пронумеровать все записи по id для каждого customer_id, то появится возможность сравнивать соседние записи. Для отображения customer_id, не отвечающим условию отбора, используем внешнее объединение.

```
[![SET DATEFORMAT YMD;

DECLARE @t table (
    id int,
    customer_id int,
    start_date date,
    end_date date
);

INSERT @t
VALUES (1, 1122, '2019-10-09', '2019-10-19'),
       (2, 1122, '2019-10-18', '2019-10-28'),
       (3, 1122, '2019-10-30', '2019-11-10'),
       (4, 1200, '2019-10-10', '2019-10-20'),
       (5, 1200, '2019-10-19', '2019-10-30'),
       (6, 1200, '2019-10-29', '2019-11-09');

WITH s AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY id) row_num, *
FROM @t
), r AS (
SELECT s1.customer_id, s1.end_date
  FROM s s1
  LEFT JOIN s s2 ON s1.customer_id = s2.customer_id
        AND s1.row_num + 1 = s2.row_num
 WHERE s1.end_date < s2.start_date
)
SELECT DISTINCT t.customer_id, r.end_date
  FROM @t t
  LEFT JOIN r ON t.customer_id = r.customer_id;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобьем задачу на 3 этапа: 1) получим customer_id,max(end_date) 2) сделаем выборку исходной таблицы исключая строки полученные на шаге 1. получим customer_id,end_date 3) из полученной выборки снова получим customer_id,max(end_date)